# Determine if the best output of a large number of model fits is due to overtraining

Tags: cross-validation, hyperparameter

I have a machine learning model (e.g. Gradient Boost Regressor). I use hyperparameter tunning (e.g. random search) in a Cross Validation loop (e.g. 5 folds) in order to recover the optimal parameters of the model.

When I run the hyperparameter tuning for a  very large number of iterations (e.g. 10^6), I get 10^6 different models.  By chance, one of these models may provide a very good regression score that happens to overfit in all the CV-folds.

Is there a good statistical test you would recommend to detect if this result is due to overfitting or random chance?

I was thinking something along the following:

- normalise the regression scores from the models and fit a standard normal distribution
- check if the best score is above the 95, 99 percentile
- if it is then it is probably due to overfitting

Is there something better you would recommend?